# using execvp to execute commands that I have in an array

Tags: c, linux, process, command, exec

I have a commands array and I want to execute each command in this array but I couldn't seem to get it working so I have

```
childPid = fork();


for(int i =0;i < numOfCommands;i++)
{
    if(childPid == 0)
    {
        execvp(commands[i], argv);
        perror("exec failure");
            exit(1);
    }
    else 
    {
        wait(&child_status);
    }


}
```

What this does, is that it only executes the 1st command in my array but doesn't proceed any further, how would I continue ?

And what if i want the order for the commands to executed randomly and the results be intermixed so do I have to use fork then ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `fork` in any case, if you want to execute more than one program. From [`man exec`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html): (emphasis added)

> The `exec()` family of functions **replaces** the current process image with a new process image.
>
> …
>
> The `exec()` functions return only if an error has occurred.

By using `fork`, you create a new process with the same image, and you can replace the image in the child process by calling `exec` without affecting the parent process, which is then free to `fork` and `exec` as many times as it wants to.

Don't forget to [`wait`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html) for the child processes to terminate. Otherwise, when they die they will become [zombies](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process). There is a complete example in the `wait` manpage, linked above.

Comment: Can you give me a simple example of how to use fork, and then I Don't need the for loop to circle through my array then if I used the fork ??

Comment: @pro: i just added a link to `man wait` (although you should have that on your machine) which includes a complete example. Of course, you still need the for loop.

Comment: Ok I edited my code, I am trying to follow this example provided here
http://www.cs.ecu.edu/karl/4630/sum01/example1.html but the thing is , if we are in the parent process how would we wait until the child is done ! should I just use waitpid() which by default wait for the chidlren to terminate ??

Comment: @pro: please don't edit your questions after they have been answered, particularly in ways which make the answer inappropriate. If you want to ask a different question, ask a different question.

Comment: I  think my code, is good now because wait(&status) puts the parent to sleep until the child is done right ??

Comment: @Pro ok I will not edit again, but my code seems to also just execute just one command

Comment: @pro: That is because you only fork once.

Comment: aha @Pro that makes a lot of sense now !! thanks pro